# Utilizing UMP SDK Consent in Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, gdprconsentform, user-messaging-platform

I'm implementing the UMP SDK in my app due to AdMob's requirement for a certified CMP. My main query is about using the UMP SDK consent result within Firebase Analytics. Specifically, how can I effectively integrate this consent data with Firebase functionalities?

Additionally, I'm curious if it's possible to use UMP SDK exclusively for Firebase Analytics for users who purchased the app and therefore do not see ads. Is there a way to configure UMP SDK to handle such scenarios where ad display isn't needed?

Any insights or experiences in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.